# git submodule and fetch

Tags: git, git-submodules, drupal-8

having trouble getting my head around submodules

They appear to be unnecessarily complicated. Normally I totally avoid them but a project has forced me into this situation

So...

I have a git repo on our dev server with a submodule

```
/myproject
          /.git
          /files ...
          /other
               /submodule
                         /.git
```

Now because we run a dev/prod environment we are very restricted in what we can do

How do I

- Clone the repo to prod such that the prod server is fully populated with the parent git and all the submodules checked out?
- How do I then...

  - update a file in other/submodule
  - commit it
  - fetch it to the cloned repo
  - then merge it in the cloned repo

We traditionally use a fetch then merge strategy rather than a single pull. Due to the very small size of the team we also do not use a bare repo.

I have tried multiple different methods of achieving the above and none of it seems right. there seems to be a very large number of steps involved so I must be doing something wrong.

Also I do not want the fetch to the prod server to fetch from the submodules remote repo.

Just so you know the project I am working on is a drupal 8 project and it is entirely inappropriate to do dev on production we do not even install composer or drush.

Comment: For those who follow... the issue appears to be I was doing my testing on an outdated version of git. Please update if you are below 1.8 it could save you hours of head scratching.

Comment: more information for those that follow. when using `git submodule add url path`. always make sure if the submodule already exists inside the git superproject that both url and path are identical e.g. `git submodule add ./path/to/submodule ./path/to/submodule` that way git understands that the submodule is already there otherwise it will try to clone it to itself

Answer (score 32, accepted):

> [Submodules] appear to be unnecessarily complicated ...

Probably true.  However, submodules are also *necessarily* complicated. :-)  I will also note that submodule support is noticeably better in Git 2.x than it was in the bad old days of Git 1.5 or 1.6 or so, which is when I learned why people called them *sob*-modules.  Some of that history is probably why some of the complexity is here.

Before I dive into the longer answer, here's the short way to get started: use `git clone --recurse-submodules`, or run `git submodule update --init --recursive` right after cloning.  (The second `--recursive` is only required if the submodule has submodules of its own.)  Adding the `--recurse-submodules` option to `git clone` just tells `git clone` to do that `git submodule update --init --recursive` after its normal sequence of operations.  Note that this *won't* help you with the process of *working within* the submodules, though.

## Long

> How do I ...

Git is a tool, not a solution (a common saying in the [construction business](http://zerringer.com/articles/technology-is-a-tool-not-a-solution/), apparently, but generally applicable to most technology).  As with most tools, there are multiple ways to use them.

The thing to know about a submodule is that each submodule is just another Git repository.  The only thing that *makes* a Git repository a "submodule" is the fact that there is some "outer later" repository that is controlling the inner repository in some way.  From within the inner repository, we refer to the outer one as the *superproject*.

Within any Git repository in which you will do any work, you have a *work-tree*.  The work-tree holds the files in their ordinary everyday form, where you (and the other programs on your computer) can work with them.  Each Git repository also has an *index*, which is where you build up the next commit you will make.  The index is also called the *staging area* and sometimes the *cache*, reflecting either its extremely important roles, or the poor choice of the word "index" for its original name (or perhaps both).  And, of course, each Git repository has a collection of *commits*, with various *branch names* and/or *tag names* that identify specific commit hashes by some sort of human-readable name.

If that Git repository were standing on its own, those names—the branch and tag names—would be the useful ones to us humans, doing work in that repository.  But we've just declared that *this* repository is a *submodule* that lives (or dies) at the command of some *other* repository—the *superproject*.  Our own branch and tag names are nearly useless.  They become useful if and when we treat *this* repository as a regular repository, not a mere adjunct to some superproject.  When we treat this repository as a controlled entity, we want this repository to have a *detached HEAD* instead.  The superproject, not the submodule therein, dictates the commit hash to check out, not by some sort of human-readable name, but by raw hash ID.

This feeds into all of the "how do I" answers.  The *superproject* records, in the superproject's index, by its raw hash ID, the specific commit that *should* be checked out in the submodule.

#### Cloning

> [How do I] Clone the repo ... such that [the clone] is fully populated with ... all the submodules checked out?

Like any clone, this can be made via `git clone url [dir]`, which really consists of about six steps:

1. Create a new, empty directory *`dir`* and switch (`cd`) to it, or use some existing empty directory if so told: `([ -d dir ] || mkdir dir) && cd dir`.  (If this fails, stop, don't do any of the remaining steps.  If a subsequent step fails, remove the new directory if we made it, and remove all the file we made, leaving no trace of the partial failed clone.)  If we don't give `git clone` a directory name, it computes one from the *`url`* argument.
2. Create a new, empty repository: `git init`.  This creates the `.git` directory and an initial configuration.
3. Do any required additional configuration from `-c` options given after `git clone`.
4. Add a *remote* given a *url:* `git remote add remote url`.  The usual name for the remote is `origin` but you can control this with the `-o` option.
5. Obtain commits from the remote: `git fetch remote`.
6. Check out some branch or tag name: `git checkout name`.  If this is a branch name, the branch does not exist yet, so this *creates* the branch the same way that `git checkout` does.  If this is a tag name, this checks out the commit as a detached HEAD.  The *`name`* here is the one you gave with a `-b` option.  If you did not give one, the name is obtained by asking the Git at the other end of the `git fetch` operation which branch *it* recommends, which is pretty commonly `main`.  If that also fails—if the other Git has no name to recommend—the name used is `main`.

The last step, step 6, checks out some specific commit, typically by getting "on" a branch such as `main`, *creating* that branch name based off the names obtained during step 5 (`git fetch` which made `origin/main`).  The act of checking out this particular commit fills in the repository's index and work-tree, so that now you have in your work-tree all the files required.

#### Submodules and *gitlinks*

If the commit you just checked out has submodules, it has a file named `.gitmodules` and has, in that commit that you just checked out, one or more special entries each called a *gitlink*.  A gitlink entry looks much like a file (`blob`) entry or a `tree` entry, but has type-code `160000` rather than `100644` (regular file) or `100755` (executable file) or `004000` (tree).<sup>1</sup>  These gitlink entries go into your index, and your Git creates an empty directory at the path given by the gitlink, the same way your Git would create a subdirectory for a `tree` or a file for a `blob`.<sup>2</sup>  The *hash ID* associated with these gitlink entries—every index entry has a hash ID—is that of *one particular commit* in the submodule, which Git can, but won't just yet, check out as a detached HEAD.

Note that I said here **if the *commit* you just checked out has submodules**.  This is another key realization: the "submodule-ness" of a submodule is controlled by the *specific commit* in the superproject.  That commit needs to have a gitlink entry, to give the hash ID to check out in the submodule, and a `.gitmodules` file.  But what is this `.gitmodules` file for?

---

<sup>1</sup>There's one more index type-code, `120000`, for symbolic links.  These are handled almost exactly the same way as `blob` objects except that as long as symlinks are enabled, Git writes the contents as a symlink rather than as a file.  If symlinks are disabled, Git writes the contents as a regular file, so that you can edit it and re-add it as a symlink later using `git update-index`, if you know all the magic for dealing with index entries.

<sup>2</sup>The fact that Git will create an empty directory for a `tree` object has led people to try to use Git's [semi-secret empty tree](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9765453/1256452) to store empty directories.  [Unfortunately, the index itself has weird corner cases here and Git turns the empty tree into a `gitlink` entry under various conditions.  This then acts as a broken submodule—a gitlink without a `.gitmodules` entry—which makes Git behave slightly badly.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8944077/1256452)

---

#### The `.gitmodules` file

We just saw, above, that `git clone` needs at least one argument: the *url* for the repository to clone.  The superproject stores the desired *commit hash ID* in the gitlink, but how will it know what *url* to use?  The answer is to look in the `.gitmodules` file.

The contents of a `.gitmodules` are formatted the same way as `.git/config` or `$HOME/.gitconfig` or any other Git configuration file, and in fact, Git uses `git config` to read them:

```
git config -f .gitmodules --get submodule.path/to/x.url
```

This looks for

```
[submodule "path/to/x"]
    url = <whatever you put here>
```

in the `.gitmodules` file, and when we find it, *that* provides the URL.

In fact, the contents will be:

```
[submodule "path/to/x"]
    path = path/to/x
    url = <whatever you put here>
```

and perhaps also one or both of:

```
    branch = <name>
    update = <control>
```

The `path` must correspond to the relative path of the submodule within the superproject, and the name of the submodule must be the relative path of the submodule within the superproject.  (What happens if one or the other of these are wrong / don't match, I am not quite sure.  Git's submodule commands generally make sure they do match, so that the question never arises.)

This lets `git submodule` find the URL to make the clone.  **This process is complicated.**  When you run `git submodule init` or `git submodule update --init`, Git will *copy* the `url` setting from `.gitmodules` to `.git/config`.  If there is an `update = control` setting, it will copy that too, unless there's already a setting in `.git/config`.  (This is one of those "unnecessary complications" you mention, though I think it's to correct for historical mistakes.)

Without `--init`, the `git submodule update` command will only look at the entries in `.git/config`, not the ones in `.gitmodules`.  This means you could use the two step sequence `git submodule init && git submodule update` to do the same thing, but `git submodule update --init` is easier to enter.  More importantly, `git submodule init` *does not* have a `--recursive` option while `git submodule update` does.  This is actually sensible, because `git submodule init` *only* copies from `.gitmodules` to `.git/config` (see below for more about this).  The `git submodule update` operation actually creates the clone, using the six-step process outlined above.

#### Detaching HEAD onto the correct commit in the submodule

We saw that the superproject lists the *correct* hash ID for the submodule, as a gitlink entry.  This means Git needs to *start* in the superproject, read the gitlink entry out of the index, then switch into the submodule (`cd path`) and `git checkout` the correct commit by its hash ID.  That will result in a detached HEAD with the correct commit checked out.

The command that does this is `git submodule update`.  And, that's usually what we want: to check out that specific commit, by its hash ID, as a detached HEAD.  Now that we've gotten what we want in the submodule, we're done ... or *are* we?  What if this Git repository—remember, each submodule is an ordinary Git repository, in its own right—what if this Git repository has submodules of its own?

#### Submodules can have submodules

If this submodule has its own submodules, we now want this sub-Git to `git checkout` the correct commit, run `git submodule init` to initialize its `.git/config` for its submodules, and run `git submodule update` to make its own submodules get checked-out to the correct commit.  That's just what `git submodule update` is already doing on behalf of our superproject, so we just want this `git submodule update` to *recursively operate on the submodule's submodules.*  This means that `git submodule update` needs to be able to recurse into submodules and also `--init` them.

So *that's* why `git submodule update --init --recursive` exists: it's the workhorse that goes into each submodule from the superproject, sets up its `.git/config` if needed, checks out the correct detached-HEAD hash, and then recurses on submodules of the submodule.

#### `git clone` can invoke `git submodule update`

If we now rewind all the way back to `git clone`, we can see that what we need after step 6 is a step 7: `git submodule update --init --recursive`, to go into each submodule listed in the superproject and initialize it and check out the correct detached HEAD, and if that submodule is a superproject of additional submodules, handle them recursively.  In the end, we'll have the superproject, with its particular commit, controlling all of its submodules which are on the correct commit as a detached HEAD, and for each of those submodules that is itself a superproject with submodules, the submodule-as-superproject's commit will control the submodule-as-superproject's submodules, recursively.

If you don't have recursive submodules, all of the recursion winds up doing nothing: it's a little bit of extra work but is harmless.  So this is usually the way to go: just run `git clone --recurse-submodules` and you get the clone created with its submodules checked out as detached HEAD repositories, and you are done.

## Working within the submodules

You had what is *almost* a separate question:

> How do I then update a file in other/submodule?

We saw above that the way a superproject controls / uses a submodule is by having the superproject specify, by absolute hash ID, which commit the submodule is to be locked into, as a detached HEAD.  That's great for controlling and using the submodule, except when we want to *update* the submodule to some newer commit.

The traditional answer, dating back to the Git 1.5 days, is that since the submodule *is* a Git repository, just `cd` into the submodule and `git checkout <branchname>` and start working.  This still works!  It has an obvious drawback, though: *how do you know which branch name to use?*

In some cases, you just know.  That's fine; go ahead and use them that way.  If you want the *superproject* to know, though, this is where the superproject's `branch =` setting comes in, and where arguments to `git submodule update` and/or the `submodule.name.update` settings (also in the superproject) come in.  Remember, these settings from from the `.git/config` file in the superproject, not from the submodule itself, and (normally<sup>3</sup>) not from the `.gitmodules` file either—but the `.gitmodules` file contents set up the default `.git/config` settings.  So there are a lot of ways to control this configuration.

Next, there's the question of what each configuration *does*, and how you want to set it up for your own purposes.  These are enumerated (rather poorly in my opinion) in [the `git submodule` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-submodule.html).  Here's my own summary of their summary, with additional commentary.

- `checkout`: the commit recorded in the superproject will be checked out in the submodule on a detached HEAD.

  This is the default and is what we saw above.
- `rebase`: the current branch of the submodule will be rebased onto the commit recorded in the superproject.

  This isn't useful unless you've already gone into the submodule and done something there.  However, there's also a `--remote` option described later in the documentation, which makes it more useful.
- `merge`: the commit recorded in the superproject will be merged into the current branch in the submodule.

  As with `rebase`, this isn't useful by itself: you need either `--remote` or to do your own work in the submodule before doing this.
- custom command: arbitrary shell command that takes a single argument (the sha1 of the commit recorded in the superproject) is executed.

  This one *is* useful by itself, but requires that you do some up-front work in the superproject, to set up the configuration and define the command.
- `none`: the submodule is not updated.

  This is primarily useful to mark a submodule that doesn't get updated when all the other submodules of this particular superproject do.  If you have only one submodule, this setting has no function at all.

So far, we have not seen any use for the `branch` setting copied from `.gitmodules` to `.git/config`.  It's this `--remote` option, described further down in the same documentation, that talks about how this setting is used:

> ... Instead of using the superproject's recorded SHA-1 to update the submodule, use the status of the submodule's remote-tracking branch.

That is, the superproject has a gitlink entry that says *use hash a1b2c3d...* or whatever, but instead of using that hash, when the superproject `git submodule update` command goes poking around with the Git repository holding the submodule, the superproject command will look up, e.g., `origin/main` in the submodule.  The name `main` here comes from that branch setting, so setting `submodule.name.branch` to, say, `develop` instead will make the superproject use `origin/develop` instead of `origin/main`.<sup>4</sup>

To make this useful, the superproject Git runs `git fetch` in the submodule before starting any of this.  That causes the submodule to bring over any new commits from *its* `origin` Git, updating *its* `origin/main`, `origin/develop`, and so on.  The assumption here is that *you* did not do any work in the submodule yourself!  You are just grabbing work that *someone else* did in the `origin` repository from which the submodule repository was cloned (whew!).

---

<sup>3</sup>The setting in `.gitmodules` will be used if there is no setting in `.git/config` and no override on the command line.  I think this is yet another backwards-compatibility item.

<sup>4</sup>This assumes that `origin/develop` is the remote-tracking name associated with branch `develop` in the submodule repository, i.e., that things are set up as normal.

---

#### Preparing the updated submodule

**If you are about to do your own work in your own submodule, none of this helps you at all.**  Instead, you should just `cd` into the submodule repository and run `git checkout branchname`.  That will take you off your detached HEAD and put you on the given branch, and now you can work normally.  Write code, `git add`, and `git commit` as you normally would.  When everything is ready in the submodule, `cd` back to the superproject.  You will have your submodule on a branch (not in detached HEAD mode), on some particular commit.

**If you *are* just picking up someone else's work**, this `git submodule update --remote --checkout` or whatever will `git fetch` and then `git checkout origin/main` or whatever, as appropriate, in the submodule.  That will leave your submodule on *no* branch, in detached HEAD mode, on some particular commit.  This is likely what you want.

#### Using the updated submodule within the superproject

Either way, from the *superproject*'s point of view, what has happened is that the submodule is now on a *different* commit.  The superproject *does not care* whether the submodule's HEAD is attached or detached; what matters is the *current commit* in the submodule.

Now that the submodule is on the desired commit, make any other changes you want in the superproject—maybe there is some file that should use some new feature of the submodule, for instance.  When you are done making the required changes, `git add` any updated files, and also **run `git add` on the submodule path** (without a trailing slash):

```
git add features.ext   # updated to use feature F of submodule sub/S
git add sub/S          # record the new gitlink for sub/S!
```

This updates the superproject's index, so that now we have not only the updated file (`features.ext`) but also the new correct hash ID for the submodule—the updated gitlink.  Now we can run `git commit` in the superproject as usual:

```
git commit
```

and this makes our new commit, which has a gitlink that records the fact that submodule `sub/S` should be checked out with a detached HEAD at commit `f37c219...` or whatever the current commit of `sub/S` actually is.  This new commit goes on whatever branch we have checked out in the superproject, whether that's `main` or `develop` or whatever.

#### Pushing

Let's say we did our own work in `sub/S`, on its branch `devel`, creating commit `f37c219...`.  Then we made our new commit in our superproject on the superproject's `main`; by some strange chance its hash ID is `abcdef1...`.  Now that we have two repositories with updates, we can `git push` them.  But there is an order constraint!

Suppose we push our superproject now:

```
git push origin main
```

Our new commit `abcdef1` goes to our upstream repository, and *that* Git's `main` now names our new commit `abcdef1`.  Our new commit says that submodule `sub/S` should be checked out at commit `f37c219`.  So Fred, over on Fred's computer, runs `git clone` or `git fetch` or whatever it is and gets *our* commit `abcdef1` that says "use commit `f37c219...` when using sub/S".  Fred runs `git submodule update` and his Git goes into his `sub/S` and tries to check out `f37c219` and, whoops, Fred doesn't *have* `f37c219`.  In fact, only *we* have `f37c219`, because we just made it!

We'd best very quickly `cd sub/S` and run `git push origin develop`.  (Remember, we made our `f37c219` on our `develop` in our submodule.)  That way, when Fred tries to access `f37c219`, it's at least available *somewhere*.  It's better if we `git push` that one *first*, *then* `git push origin main` in the superproject, to push `abcdef1` which refers to `f37c219`.  So this leads to update rule #2: **push the submodules first, in deepest-submodule order.**  That way each superproject refers to a commit that Fred—or whoever—can get to.

#### There is still one more minor pain point for Fred

We introduced Fred above as the first guy to fetch (and merge or rebase or otherwise incorporate, perhaps even `git pull`) our superproject commit that refers to new subproject commits.  However, Fred here stands in for *anyone* who has cloned our superproject.  They all have our superproject, and they all ran `git submodule update --init --recursive`, perhaps as part of the very clone command that got them the superproject, so they have all the submodules already.

But they don't have *any of the new commits in the submodules* yet.  When they update their superproject and tell their Git to `git submodule update`, their Gits will go into their submodules and *not find the right commit hashes*.  Fortunately, `git submodule update` is smart enough to run `git fetch` for you (or for Fred).

For this to work, though, whoever is updating has to be on line.  This means you must run `git submodule update` when connected.  If you're always connected, that's no problem, but if not, there should be an easy way to fetch all submodules up front.

There's no `git submodule fetch`, but there is a command that will do the trick:

```
git submodule foreach --recursive git fetch
```

This will run `git fetch` in each submodule, to update it.  That way a later `git submodule update`, used with any commit in the superproject, will work even if you are off line and the submodules would have required updating.

Comment: thank you for your very long response. Too much for me to comment on and I haven't absorbed a large percentage of it. but with reference to your short response  I tried multiple commands and `git clone --recurse-submodules` did not populate the working directory of the submodule, it was there, but was an empty folder.

Comment: Hmm I made a mistake in my formatting `How do I then update a file in other/submodule?` was not meant to be on one line and altered the context a bit. though your response still applies. my humble apologies.

Comment: there was an error in my .gitmodules file which prevented cloning from working correctly the url attribute was blank. Ok so one issue fixed :)

Comment: still not there yet. I went into the submodule (inside the superproject) deleted a file. commited that file change in the submodule, added the submodule again in the superproject, committed the change. switched to the clone, fetched and merged the source superproject. ran `git ls...` it said the submodule was at the correct commit. ran `git submodule update` in the superproject and got an error "reference is not a tree'

Comment: `git ls`? is that an alias, and if so, for what? (`git: 'ls' is not a git command. See 'git --help'. The most similar commands are ...`) That error message is odd as well, since submodule references are not *supposed* to be trees, they are gitlinks and gitlinks identify a commit hash, not a tree hash.

Comment: sorry for my poor shorthand I meant `git ls-files --stage submodule`

Comment: Ah, so that shows `160000 <hash> 0    submodule`? (That would indicate that `submodule` is a gitlink entry with the given `<hash>`.) What about the contents of `.gitmodules`, or the output from the top level inspection command, `git submodule status`?

Comment: Yes. When I use `git submodule status` I get a hash plus the path to the submodule. the hash is the actual commit in the submodule. the .gitmodule contains the relative path and the url is the full path. the submodule was created inside the superproject there is no external repo

Comment: Hm: *and the URL is the full path* ... I've never tested this case. It seems like it should work, but maybe there's something weird with that. What happens if you make it a `file://` URL?

Comment: I added file: committed the change in the source superproject fetched and merged in the destination and then tried a `git submodule update` and got the same reference is not a tree message

Comment: Let's back up a bit here ... what version of Git are you using?

Comment: git version 1.7.10.4. I also think I have some corruption or something going on so I am completely removing the submodule and going to re-add it. I'll let you know if that improves matters.

Comment: Aha. You have a very old Git—anything before 1.8, submodules were "sob"-modules. If you can, install a modern Git. At the very least, upgrade to 1.8.4 if possible.

Comment: Oh thats the latest in my debian repo. I'll get a later version and try again. Really appreciate all the help and very full explanations.

Comment: Hmm still having issues. I think the problem is related to git assuming the submodule is an external repo. in the test case I am building there is no external repo its simply a subfolder with a git repo in it. when I do `git submodule add ./path/to/repo` it clones the repo into ./repo which is incorrect. even though add specifically asks for a relative url it still doesnt realise it is within the git repo.

Comment: That's at least part of why I was suggesting a `file://` repo (which always has an absolute path name). Git does try to guess whether submodule URLs are relative to the superproject URL as well, so that could also / still go wrong.

Comment: Came looking for `git submodule foreach --recursive git fetch` and got a gold mine instead 5★